# Pandas заголовки Датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, replace

Как ко всем заголовкам столбцов pandas дата фрейма применить функцию замены пробела на нижнее подчëркивание? `replace(' ','_')`

Comment: df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(" ", "_")

Comment: А как применить   str.replace к значениям столбцов из списка?

Comment: А вы пример данных и кода в вопросе приведите, как того требуют правила сайта.

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю так:

```
column = ['new features 1', 'new features 2']
column = str(column).replace(' ','_')
print(column)
```